# One socket connection per cluster

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, jboss-eap-6, jboss-seam

I have an webapp built with Jboss Seam, which runs on cluster Jboss EAP. Webapp have a [client library](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Java_ESL_Client), which should stay connected with server for receiving events. When event arrived from client, it fires JMS message. The question is how can I achieve only one client connection per cluster(to avoid JMS message duplication) in this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly Clustering Singleton Services might work for your problem. See reference https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/4/html/ch05s11.html

For a more details reference, see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Implement_an_HA_Singleton.html

Hope that helps